# create a cumulative count, until 2 of previous 6 rows meet a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If column a is equal to 1, I would like to start a cumulative sum. I would like to stop when 2 of the previous 6 rows is equal to 0.

```
dplyr::tibble(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
          sum = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3))
```

sum is my desired output

Ideally using `tidyverse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to find out row where two consecutive 0's are found within interval of 6 rows, then use `cumsum` to create groups and final take `cumsum` value in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
   mutate(sum1 = map_dbl(seq_along(a), ~sum(a[. : max(.-6, 1)] == 0) >= 2)) %>%
   group_by(group = cumsum(sum1 != lag(sum1, default = first(sum1)))) %>%
   mutate(ans = cumsum(a)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-sum1, -group)

# A tibble: 14 x 2
#      a   ans
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     1     3
# 4     1     4
# 5     1     5
# 6     1     6
# 7     1     7
# 8     1     8
# 9     0     8
#10     1     9
#11     0     0
#12     1     1
#13     1     2
#14     1     3
```